# Speeding up random number generation by parallelizing

Tags: python, numpy, random, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I need to create many large numpy arrays (4e6, 100) with random numbers from a standard normal distribution, which I'm trying to speed up. I tried to generate different parts of the arrays using multiple cores but I'm not getting the expected speed improvements. Is there something I'm doing wrong, or am I wrong to expect speed improvements in this way?

```py
from numpy.random import default_rng
from multiprocessing import Pool
from time import time


def rng_mp(rng):
    return rng.standard_normal((250000, 100))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    n_proc = 4
    rngs = [default_rng(n) for n in range(n_proc)]
    rng_all = default_rng(1)

    start = time()
    result = rng_all.standard_normal((int(1e6), 100))
    print(f'Single process: {time() - start:.3f} seconds')

    start = time()
    with Pool(processes=n_proc) as p:
        result = p.map_async(rng_mp, rngs).get()
    print(f'MP: {time() - start:.3f} seconds')

    # Single process: 1.114 seconds
    # MP: 2.634 seconds
```

Comment: If you're really getting a multiprocessing duration of ~2.6s with those values I wouldn't complain. I tried this on my 3GHz 10-core Intel Xeon W and it took more like ~10s

Comment: Did you also use 4 cores or did you increase the number of cores? I have a i7-6700HQ 2.6GHz Intel. The issue is rather the comparison with the single-process speed, I don't get why multiprocessing is slower.

Comment: It's rather likely that the NumPy implementation already uses multiple cores, so you're just adding overhead. From [here](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ParallelProgramming.html#): _"... But many architectures now have a BLAS that also takes advantage of a multicore machine. If your numpy/scipy is compiled using one of these, then dot() will be computed in parallel (if this is faster) without you doing anything. ..."_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspected the slowdown results simply from the fact that you need to be moving lots of data from the address spaces of the subprocesses back to the main process. I also suspected that the C-language implementation `numpy` used for random number generation releases the Global Interpreter Lock and that using multithreading instead of multiprocessing would solve your performance problem:

```py
from numpy.random import default_rng
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from time import time


def rng_mp(rng):
    return rng.standard_normal((250000, 100))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    n_proc = 4
    rngs = [default_rng(n) for n in range(n_proc)]
    rng_all = default_rng(1)

    start = time()
    result = rng_all.standard_normal((int(1e6), 100))
    print(f'Single process: {time() - start:.3f} seconds')

    start = time()
    with ThreadPool(processes=n_proc) as p:
        result = p.map_async(rng_mp, rngs).get()
    print(f'MT: {time() - start:.3f} seconds')
```

Prints:

```
Single process: 1.210 seconds
MT: 0.413 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not meant as an answer to the original question - more of a follow-up that begs more questions than I can answer.

I have rearranged the code to try to see what's really going on here.

```
from numpy.random import default_rng
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import time

NPROC = 4

def rng_mp(i):
    s = time.perf_counter()
    r = default_rng(i).standard_normal((250000, 100))
    e = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Process {i} {e-s:.2f}s')
    return r


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.perf_counter()
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for fr in [executor.submit(rng_mp, i) for i in range(NPROC)]:
            s = time.perf_counter()
            fr.result()
            e = time.perf_counter()
            print(f'Result time {e-s:.2f}')
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(f'Overall {end - start:.3f} seconds')
```

A typical output from this is as follows:

Process 0 0.33s
Process 2 0.33s
Process 1 0.33s
Process 3 0.33s
Result time 2.27
Result time 5.57
Result time 0.00
Result time 0.00
Overall 7.999 seconds

In other words, the ring_mp() process executes in good time. **BUT** the delay appears to be in acquiring the result which I can only guess is something to do with moving large amounts of memory between the sub- and main processes. FWIW I'm running numpy 1.21.4 with Python 3.9.8 on macOS 12.0.1. I cannot explain this.

UPDATE: Based on the answer from @Booboo I changed to using the ThreadPoolExecutor (no other changes needed) with the following results:

Process 3 0.34s
Process 1 0.35s
Process 0 0.35s
Result time 0.35
Result time 0.00
Process 2 0.35s
Result time 0.00
Result time 0.00
Overall 0.388 seconds

Answer (score 0):

I'm obliged to the other contributors for coming up with this, but I found a way which is faster than the other suggestions, as it uses the filling of an existing array instead of creating new ones. It's an adaptation of the numpy documentation [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/multithreading.html), optimized for 2d arrays.

```py
from numpy.random import default_rng, SeedSequence
import multiprocessing
import concurrent.futures
import numpy as np
from time import time


class MultithreadedRNG2D:
    def __init__(self, shape, seed=None, threads=None):
        if threads is None:
            threads = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
        self.threads = threads

        seq = SeedSequence(seed)
        self._random_generators = [default_rng(s)
                                   for s in seq.spawn(threads)]

        self.shape = shape
        self.executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(threads)
        self.values = np.empty(shape)
        self.steps = [(t * (shape[0] // threads), (t + 1) * (shape[0] // threads))
                      if t < (threads - 1)
                      else (t * (shape[0] // threads), shape[0])
                      for t in range(threads)]

    def fill(self):
        def _fill(random_state, out, firstrow, lastrow):
            random_state.standard_normal(out=out[firstrow:lastrow])

        futures = {}
        for i in range(self.threads):
            args = (_fill,
                    self._random_generators[i],
                    self.values,
                    self.steps[i][0],
                    self.steps[i][1])
            futures[self.executor.submit(*args)] = i
        concurrent.futures.wait(futures)

    def __del__(self):
        self.executor.shutdown(False)


mrng = MultithreadedRNG2D((int(1e6), 100), seed=1, threads=4)
start = time()
mrng.fill()
print(f'MT: {time() - start:.3f} seconds')

# MT: 0.336 seconds
```

Comment: to be fair, you should put `mrng = MultithreadedRNG2D((int(1e6), 100), seed=1, threads=4)` to timing as well

Comment: Perhaps, but in my case I need to create many arrays of the same shape where I would only need to instantiate once, so the execution time of the `fill` matters most. This is also why i'm just adding it here as a reference but don't have it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The logic from my other answer is now implemented in a package [mtalg](https://github.com/WWakker/mtalg) designed for generating random numbers using multithreading.

```py
from mtalg.random import MultithreadedRNG
mrng = MultithreadedRNG(seed=1, num_threads=4)
mrng.standard_normal(size=(int(1e6), 100))
```